# UITableViewCell Content Disappearing after scrolling

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

[image] [image: Second Image] [image: Third Image].

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DateTableViewCell") as! DateTableViewCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.dayOfWeekLabel.text = currentDayOfWeek
            cell.monthDateLabel.text = "\(currentMonth!) \(currentDay!)"
            cell.yearLabel.text = currentYear

            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MonthWeekTableViewCell") as! MonthWeekTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.monthYear = (currentMonth,currentYear)

            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 2{

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MonthWeekTableViewCell") as! MonthWeekTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.monthYear = ("May",currentYear)
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MonthWeekTableViewCell") as! MonthWeekTableViewCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            cell.monthYear = ("June",currentYear)
            return cell
        }

    }
```

The moment I scroll up in down the tableview the cell containing the content for months April and May disappear. Yet, when the view is loaded I could see the content for April and May. But, once I start scrolling to the bottom and scroll back up I can't see April Content anymore.

Cell Code:

```
import UIKit

class MonthWeekTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var monthLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var dayCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    var monthYear: (String,String) = ("","") {
        didSet {
            monthLabel.text = self.monthYear.0

            guard let _maxDate = DateFormat.returnNumberOfDaysInMonth(month: self.monthYear.0, year: self.monthYear.1) else {fatalError("Tuple Error")}
            maxDate = _maxDate

            firstDay = DateFormat.getFirstOfMonth(year: self.monthYear.1, month: self.monthYear.0)
        }
    }
    var firstDay: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            dayCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    var dayNumber: Int = 1

    var maxDate: Int = 30

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        dayCollectionView.delegate = self
        dayCollectionView.dataSource = self
        dayCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "DayCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DayCollectionViewCell")
        dayCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "DayCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DayCollectionViewCell
        if (indexPath.section != 0 || (indexPath.row + 1) >= firstDay) && dayNumber <= maxDate{

            cell.dayLabel.text = String(dayNumber)
            dayNumber += 1
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        } else {

            cell.isHidden = true

        }

        return cell
    }



}
```

Comment: Could you try adding breakpoints or print statements to your code to figure out where things could be going wrong?

Comment: show numberOfRows

Comment: @Sh_Khan the correct numberOfRows are shown

Comment: I think I found the error in which the dayNumber variable's value isn't resetting after the first 2 tableview cells are loaded. I don't know how to reset the value. I tried resetting the value when initializing the cell, but then many errors are caused. @rpecka

Answer (score 0):

To reset the state of your cell between uses, you can override the cell's `prepareForReuse` function documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse). That function will get called on a cell when you call `dequeueReusableCell` so you can use that function to return the cell to a basic state before reconfiguring it in you `cellForItemAt` function.

```swift
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse() // make sure you include this
    dayNumber = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that there were two problems in my code.
1) as mentioned from @rpecka, I needed to override the function prepareForReuse

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
         super.prepareForReuse()
         dayNumber = 1
    }
```

2) also I needed to unhide the buttons during their use

```
cell.isHidden = false
```